# How to get the throughput of KafkaSource in Flink？

Tags: apache-flink

I want to know the throughput of KafkaSource. In other words, I want to measure the speed at which flink reads data. My idea is to add a map operator after the Source and use the built-in Metrics in the map operator. Will this increase the overhead? I hope to get this metric without adding a lot of overhead. what should I do? Or is there a way to get the output throughput of this topic in kafka? Or should I get KafkaSource's NumberOutPersecond through the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kafka Manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) which displays a lot of metrics related to Kafka. It's a tool which is used to manage Kafka and acts as a real-time dashboard. You need to install and configure this separately.

This can be used to check the consumption rate for your Flink consumer.

You can also make use of built-in metrics publisher on the source operator without using a Map only for that purpose.

Comment: As mentioned by @shriyog, you have out of the box metrics for any sources (not only kafka) in flink. It's explained here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#io So in theory you don't have to write any code, you just need to set up the monitoring.

Comment: @shriyog，but I found that the topic Metrics in kafka-manager does not have Messages out /sec, only Messages in /sec. I want out/sec of this topic.

Comment: @Arthur，When I use the REST API, where can I know the value that should be entered in `<vertexid>` in `/jobs/<jobid>/vertices/<vertexid>/subtasks/metrics`？

Comment: It gets complicated: First you query /jobs and it gives you the list of job ids. Then you query jobs/<job-id> and from there you can get a list of the vertices for each job. I've never done it, what I've done instead is set up influxdb & grafana and I have flink publish to influxdb.